# text animation using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I would like an animation in which the letters of a word move from right to left on a page to rest at the centre of the page.

Also the letters of the word should become a hyperlink after the animation.

Can i achieve all above things with the help of html, css, jquery ??

Comment: That can definitely be done, do you have anything that you've tried so far?

Comment: nope .. havent done anything like this before :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a fiddle for you to get you started.

http://jsfiddle.net/YCwm3/5/

Basically by using animate which has a `complete` callback to do whatever you want with the text once the animation is complete

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

yes you can achieve this with jquery.

Have a look at this jquery plugin: http://www.giuliandrimba.com/labs/lettering-animate/

it helps you animating letters (which are separated by the lettering plugin)

there are also some demos and you have many possibilities to implement your own animation

Comment: Thanks i guess it will serve the purpose :-)

Answer (score 1):

*Can i achieve all above things with the help of html, css, jquery ??*

Yes this can be achieved using jquery+html+css....

You can start from here
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

[animateText.js](http://lukeas14.github.com/animateText.js/) is a text animation jQuery plugin built specifically for this exact purpose. Use the leftToRight animation and set the positions where you'd like the text to start and stop.

Disclaimer - I created animateText.js